# Date processing in NestJS

Tags: angular, nestjs, typeorm

My NestJS API is returning a string in format 'YYYY-mm-dd' and I want it to format like 'dd-mm-YYYY', or a date object if it is possible.

The NestJS do not recognize when Angular send a Date too. Do I need to send it as string in a specific way or Nest can convert it?

I'm looking for answers for some time and docs, but did not find any

**My entity is like:**

```js
export class Example {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('date', { nullable: true })
  date: Date;
}
```

**The result that the API returns is like:**

```js
[
  {
    'id': '1',
    'date': '2020-06-25'
  }
]
```

Comment: please let me know if you found my answer helpful... thank'

Answer (score 7):

> **Serialization** 
> Nest provides a built-in capability to help ensure that these operations can be performed in a straightforward way. The `ClassSerializerInterceptor` interceptor uses the powerful [Class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) package to provide a declarative and extensible way of transforming objects. The basic operation it performs is to take the value returned by a method handler and apply the `classToPlain()` function from `class-transformer`. In doing so, it can apply rules expressed by class-transformer decorators on an entity/DTO class, as described below.

> **Transform** 
> You can perform additional data transformation using the `@Transform()` decorator. 
>  For example, the following construct returns the name property of the RoleEntity instead of returning the whole object. 
>      `@Transform(role => role.name)` 
> `role: RoleEntity;`

([from Nest.js Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization))

You can modify your code as follows:

```js
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class Example {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Transform(x => new Date(x))
  @Column('text')
  date: Date;
}
```

Or:

```js
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class Example {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Type(() => Date)
  @Column('text')
  date: Date;
}
```

As a best practice, consider having your Angular app send the date as `Date` type, then store it in the DB as a `Date`.